# Had the Eastern empires started colonizing territories which territory would bring to whom

Tags: alternate-history, colonization

In my world empires of the east like empires from China, India, and Indochina attempt a colonization of the Americas, Australia etc. Now considering that this colonization started in the 1400s and our colonizing contestants are (in no particular order):

- Vijaynagar Empire
- Ming Dynasty
- Bengal sultanate
- Khmer Empire
- Madurai
- Ceylon.

The regions open for colonials are:

- Americas
- Indonesia
- Australia

In this case which territories would be colonized by which empires.

*PS: in making the SE asian political landscape I have used Europa Universalis IV. if there is any mistake feel free to correct it.

Comment: You have a world based on a game. Your question screams computer game logic. Do you really want to ask about the real world (question makes no sense in that case) or about a world within some other (e.g computer game) logic? If so explain that logic

Comment: What do you mean by the "Madurai" empire, *especially* in the 15th century? My knowledge of these states is vague at best, but: the Vijaynagar Empire and the Khmer Empire were archetypal "oriental" states, land-based powers with socio-economic systems already thousands of years out of date by the 15th century; see [Asiatic mode of production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiatic_mode_of_production) and [hydaulic empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_empire)... Ming China, *maybe*, possibly; but Ming China took the firm decision to stay put and stagnate and it stuck to it.

Comment: It can go in multiple directions. The fact that yoiu did not include Japan (a major naval power in Asia) or Majapahit (Indonesia) is an indication that this is opinion based. For example on how small things can have a big impact, Portugal tried to colonize Newfoundland before the French or the British. They left the island because it was too cold. If they had stayed longer, they would have found that it is among the best fishing spot in the world, The desicion of only one person could have changed the history of the island and maybe of the whole region.

Comment: As a fellow EUIV fan, this question in fascinating. The obvious colonization winner is Majapahit :) However, this is far to broad to be answered in the space available on this site. There are so many possible outcomes, that there is no way to determine which is the _correct_ answer, so this question is "opinion based."

Comment: What about availability of oversees travel? You need to cross quite lot of sea to get to Australia or America from Asia. As far as I understand the Great Geographical Discoveries, they were made possible by a) economical pressure in the to-be-metropole states; b) availability of intercontinental sea fare. Even assuming (a), does Ming China or other your candidates have (b)?

Comment: And, by the way, what about Zulu Empire or Abyssinia?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use EU as base material, you would have problems, because the game does not intent to be historically accurate. China was the only of these who tried to do long range navigations. In fact, they not colonized big parts of the world because of internal affairs. See [Treasure voyages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasure_voyages) for more information.

You can make a alternative history where these nations also tried, but the changes from our history would be much more radical. So, the answer is Ming Dynasty. But the colonized areas would be in Africa.